# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named qiskit.providers

Tags: programming, qiskit

The following message I got by running the [qft.py code](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/blob/master/examples/python/qft.py)

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "qft.py", line 18, in

```
from qiskit.providers.ibmq import least_busy
```

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named qiskit.providers`

---

This the code snippet (from the QISKit repository):

I suppose that something was wrong with the installation process?)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Copyright 2017, IBM.
#
# This source code is licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 found in
# the LICENSE.txt file in the root directory of this source tree.

"""
Quantum Fourier Transform examples.
Note: if you have only cloned the Qiskit repository but not
used `pip install`, the examples only work from the root directory.
"""

import math
from qiskit import QuantumRegister, ClassicalRegister, QuantumCircuit
from qiskit import execute, BasicAer, IBMQ
from qiskit.providers.ibmq import least_busy


###############################################################
# make the qft
###############################################################
def input_state(circ, q, n):
    """n-qubit input state for QFT that produces output 1."""
    for j in range(n):
        circ.h(q[j])
        circ.u1(math.pi/float(2**(j)), q[j]).inverse()


def qft(circ, q, n):
    """n-qubit QFT on q in circ."""
    for j in range(n):
        for k in range(j):
            circ.cu1(math.pi/float(2**(j-k)), q[j], q[k])
        circ.h(q[j])


q = QuantumRegister(5, "q")
c = ClassicalRegister(5, "c")
qft3 = QuantumCircuit(q, c, name="qft3")
qft4 = QuantumCircuit(q, c, name="qft4")
qft5 = QuantumCircuit(q, c, name="qft5")

input_state(qft3, q, 3)
qft3.barrier()
qft(qft3, q, 3)
qft3.barrier()
for j in range(3):
    qft3.measure(q[j], c[j])

input_state(qft4, q, 4)
qft4.barrier()
qft(qft4, q, 4)
qft4.barrier()
for j in range(4):
    qft4.measure(q[j], c[j])

input_state(qft5, q, 5)
qft5.barrier()
qft(qft5, q, 5)
qft5.barrier()
for j in range(5):
    qft5.measure(q[j], c[j])

print(qft3)
print(qft4)
print(qft5)

###############################################################
# Set up the API and execute the program.
###############################################################
try:
    IBMQ.load_accounts()
except:
    print("""WARNING: There's no connection with the API for remote backends.
             Have you initialized a file with your personal token?
             For now, there's only access to local simulator backends...""")

print('Qasm simulator')
sim_backend = BasicAer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')
job = execute([qft3, qft4, qft5], sim_backend, shots=1024)
result = job.result()
print(result.get_counts(qft3))
print(result.get_counts(qft4))
print(result.get_counts(qft5))

# Second version: real device
least_busy_device = least_busy(IBMQ.backends(simulator=False,
                                             filters=lambda x: x.configuration().n_qubits > 4))
print("Running on current least busy device: ", least_busy_device)
job = execute([qft3, qft4, qft5], least_busy_device, shots=1024)
result = job.result()
print(result.get_counts(qft3))
print(result.get_counts(qft4))
print(result.get_counts(qft5))
```

Answer (score 3):

This issue was due to you taking example code using the master branch, and running it using the stable version (which is installed when you `pip install qiskit`).

Since this question was asked, Qiskit has been updated. The program given in the question will now run fine with the stable version of Qiskit.

If you ever want to run code from the master branch, you can pip install the relevant version of Qiskit using

```
pip install git+https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra.git
```